# Getting javascript to not run a certain code if a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, button, slideshow

Hello and apologies if my question is unclear due to the lack of my javascript knowledge. I am a self-taught php:er and decided to try javascript with a php approach. So here's my problem:

**I want to make a slideshow of pictures which:**

1) have buttons to go next/prev pic,  (works)

2) automatically changes picture every X seconds, (works)

3) stops changing pictures automatically after the whole series of pictures have been previewed, (works)

4) stops changing pictures automatically if the next/prev button has been pressed. (doesn't work)

1 - 3 I have managed to figure out. But for reasons beyond my pathetic understanding I can't do #4! I have tried to set a *"lap"* variable if the *"n"* variable is set. Which I thought meant that if the "next/prev" button has been pressed, *lap* will be set and the javascript codes will not read the line which *settimeout* the showSlides. It hasn't worked no matter how many different ways I try it! Can you help me please? Here are my codes:

CSS below

```
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: #595959;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 38px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  top:50px;
  right: 0;
}

.prev {
  top:50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

HTML below

```
<td class='slideshow-container' valign='top' style='width:50%;padding:3%;text-align:center;'>
    <center>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='forsig.JPG' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='grundblocket.JPG' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='kajaky.JPG' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='Rescueshot1.jpg' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='rescueshot2.jpg' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
        <div class='mySlides fade' style='position:relative;'>
        <img src='skoretc.JPG' style='width:90%'>
        </div>
    echo "</center>
    <a class='prev' onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
    <a class='next' onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
</td>
```

Javascript below:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}  
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  if (typeof n == 'undefined') {slideIndex++;}
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (slideIndex == slides.length) {var lap = "ye"}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  if (typeof lap == 'undefined') {
     if (typeof n == 'undefined') {setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);}
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you declare 'lap' inside an if statement, but then call it outside of that if statement.  it's not clear/reliable what lap would represent at that point.  recommend you declare it above, set it with a default value and change it based on your if statement instead.  Plus, you can make it just a boolean rather than using all that typeof stuff

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Phil! it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `var lap;` on the top where `var slideIndex = 0;` goes, replace `var lap = "ye";` with `lap = "ye";` Now, you can set `lap` variable with any other funciton and it will stop autoplay.
Leaving some details for you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks crtag! You guys are the best, it works now :) I also made the setTimeout a var, and added a clearTimeout() to make it stop straight away, and not after the initial settimeout had passed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code now doing what I want it to do:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
var lap
var to
showSlides();

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}  
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  if (typeof n == 'undefined') {slideIndex++;}
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (slideIndex == slides.length) {lap = "ye"}
  if (typeof n !== 'undefined') {
      lap = "ye";
      clearTimeout(to);
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  if (typeof lap == 'undefined') {
     if (typeof n == 'undefined') {to = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000);}
  }
}
</script>
```